# when i make && make install the glibc-2.27 failed with Error 1 and Error2

Tags: odoo, glibc

```
/opt/odoo/glibc-2.27/elf/../sysdeps/posix/dl-fileid.h:37: undefined reference to `__GI___fxstat64'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/odoo/glibc-2.27/build/elf/librtld.os: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__GI___fxstat64' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:478: recipe for target '/opt/odoo/glibc-2.27/build/elf/ld.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/opt/odoo/glibc-2.27/build/elf/ld.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/odoo/glibc-2.27/elf'
Makefile:215: recipe for target 'elf/subdir_lib' failed
make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/odoo/glibc-2.27'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

how i can solut the problem, the unix is Debain. The proble i can't make the glic-2.27

Comment: Use `apt` since you are on `Debain`.

Comment: Which Debian version are you building on?